# Using TestBed from core/testing with Jest in Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ErrorsService } from './errors.service';
import { MessageService } from './services/message.service';
 
describe('ErrorsService', () => {
  let errorService: ErrorsService;
  let messageServiceMock;
 
  beforeEach(() => {
    messageServiceMock = new (MessageService as jest.MockedClass<typeof MessageService>)();
 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ErrorsService,
        { provide: MessageService, useValue: messageServiceMock },
      ],
    });
 
    errorService = TestBed.inject(ErrorsService);
  });
 
  it('should call sendMessage once when setError is called', () => {
 
    errorService.setError(null);
 
    expect(messageServiceMock.sendMessage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

So I tried this and I couldn't get it to work. The method doesn't detect the fact that it's getting called. https://angular.io/guide/testing-services The example that the Angular team provides uses Karma and Jasmine, but when switching to Jest it doesn't seem like I can fully use all of the methods like TestBed fully. Is there a way to make it work? Another thing is that it's difficult to mock services with several dependencies injected to it, so I am wondering if there are ways around this.